# tabula-py - "No module named requests"

Tags: python, tabula

I'm make "scripts.py" with code (https://github.com/chezou/tabula-py#example) and when I start "python scripts.py" I got this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tabula
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tabula/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .wrapper import read_pdf_table
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tabula/wrapper.py", line 16, in <module>
    import requests
ImportError: No module named requests
```

OS: Ubuntu 16.04

Java: 1.8.0_121

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install requests: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/install/#install

Comment: he will probably need to install more than that https://github.com/chezou/tabula-py/blob/master/requirements.txt

Answer (score 0):

I'm an author of tabula-py. Added requests dependency on v0.6.1.
https://github.com/chezou/tabula-py/blob/master/setup.py#L41